# can i extract the icon image from vista application? (mainly word and pdf)

Tags: windows-vista, icons, extract

i'm trying to extract the icon that shown in vista for pdf and word files. is there anyways for me to do so? also, the icon i want is the big one (128px by 128px probably?)

a screenshot:
[alt text http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/756/capturehmb.jpg](http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/756/capturehmb.jpg)

Comment: ...have you tried cutting out that image in a graphics editor and saving it?

Answer (score 2):

Using something like [this](http://www.rw-designer.com/batch-icon-extractor)? Unless you mean using code of course, in, you know, a programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe provide icons [here](http://www.adobe.com/misc/linking.html#pdficon), with appropriate licensing restrictions. I don't know if MS provide a similar thing for Word.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Windows\Installer\{90120000-0030-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\wordicon.exe`

I found the icon in above file path in my computer.